# Minecraft Black Screen

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have installed Minecraft on my laptop running i686 Debian Wheezy. When I try and run Minecraft it started but showed a black screen. It started playing music and when I click on certain areas of the window it makes click noises.

Launcher Log: http://pastebin.com/AYC0A3Mu

Game Output: http://pastebin.com/UKD8TYMn

Comment: ... what are the system specs of this laptop you are trying to run Minecraft on? Based on your mention of i686, my guess would be that your laptop [might not meet minecraft's *minimum* requirements](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/325948-minecraft-system-requirements)

Comment: Sounds like you are having OpenGL issues

Comment: What version of  Java are you running?

Comment: @Isaac the Java version is mentioned in the logs; it's 1.6.

Comment: Make sure java is up to date, as well as OpenGl, and then go to this website: [Can you run it?](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri), find minecraft, and check and see what it says about your computer. You may need to download a tool, or use java, but trust me, it works for every game released.

Comment: try downloading from http://launcher.mojang.com/download/Minecraft_legacy.dmg

Comment: Outdated Video Card drivers could be the problem. Did you try to update them?

Comment: Try Playing MC in a smaller window.

Answer (score 1):

As people said in the comments, you could check:

- Your technical parameters. Graphics card, RAM, processor, Disk memory
- If you have any software problems.  Outdated Java, too old Launcher or OS - do you run the game Fullscreen?
- If you have misdownloaded/not properly updated Minecraft. You could try reinstalling Minecraft (the Launcher too).